# Adding menu items in an optionMenu in Maya

Tags: python, qt, maya

I created a GUI through qt designer and I want to have that GUI be used in Maya (I don't think it matters but I am using 2015). I have a lot of code but I am just going to show an example. Basically I have a combo box and I want to add items to that box. I want to add some specific items using a loop and some lists but Maya won't even let me just specify items to add, I just want to be able to first figure out how to explicitly add items to the optionMenu:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

win = cmds.loadUI("Path/To/Ui.ui")
oM = cmds.optionMenu("objectNameOfOptionMenu",query=True)
cmds.menuItem(label='Test',p=oM)
cmds.showWindow(win)
```

The error it typically gives me is that "menu item's menu not found maya". Is it possible to do this or do I have to program my own gui if I want to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to get the optionMenu's full path before you query it -- it will probably include the window path as well as the menu path.  You can see all the existing optionMenus with `cmds.lsUI(type ='optionMenu')`

Comment: Can you elaborate on giving a full path? The individual components of my gui don't have a path to themselves, they are all contained in the .ui file.

Comment: When they get instantiated in maya they will have a path name, like "window1|formLayout2|button3"    The exact path will depend on what's already in the scene - like the regular maya scene you can't have siblings with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the flag `menuBar` of your object `win` to `True`